# Minimum number of consecutive elements that must be chosen when choosing $\frac{3n}{4}$ elements from a sequence of length $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Given a sequence of length $n$, $S = (x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n$), I need to choose $\frac{3n}{4}$ elements such that I minimize the choice of consecutive elements (called a "square").

That is, $(x_i \cdot x_{i+1})$ would be counted as choosing 1 square, while choosing $(x_i \cdot x_{i+1} \cdot x_{i+2})$ is counted as choosing 2 squares.

What is the minimum number of squares that will be chosen when choosing $\frac{3n}{4}$ elements from a sequence of length $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose $x_i$, it will be the first part of a square unless $x_{i+1}$ is not chosen or $i=n$. It happens at moset $\frac n4$ times that $x_{i+1}$ is not chosen. Hence we have at least $\frac34n-1-\frac n4=\frac12n-1$ squares. This bound can be achieved e.g. by chosing all but $x_2,x_4,x_6,\ldots, x_{n/2}$. (I assume that $\mid n$)